# QR Reading API is throwing Exception for some images

Tags: java, qr-code

I am trying to read QR code using `google.zxing`. And following is the code which I used to read it.

```
Result result = null;
BinaryBitmap binaryBitmap;
FileInputStream pngInput = null;
try {
    pngInput = new FileInputStream("D:\\TestQR.png");
    binaryBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(ImageIO.read(pngInput))));
    result = new MultiFormatReader().decode(binaryBitmap,null);
}catch (Exception e) {
    throw e;
}finally {
    if(pngInput != null) {
        pngInput.close();
    }
}
System.out.println(result.getText());
```

Now above code is working fine for some images and throwing NullPointerException for some of them. I checked with that Image but that image is completely fine and readable with Mobile app.
Is there any other third party API which resolved this issue? Else any code change required in above lines?

Here is the Image which is causing issue for me.
[image]

Comment: Hi. Can you provide the stack trace? Also, a copy of the image would be useful.

Comment: I have edited Question with Image.

Answer (score 0):

"the image is completely fine" means nada, nothing, zip, zilch, zero.
And without more information about where and what the exact NPE is nobody's going to be able to tell you anything about what's wrong with your code or image.
But do realise that simply because something is a valid QR code doesn't mean you have a valid image file on your harddisk representing it.
Or simply because a png can be read by one application that it's valid and won't throw a spanner if you try to read it in another.
Either the image file is corrupt, or it does not contain a valid QR code according to the decoder (which could hint at some corruption).
The latter is rather likely, as something can be a corrupt QR code yet readable by a QR code scanner because of the error detection systems employed by those, error detection systems that are likely bypassed when reading from file.

Answer (score 0):

The QR code you posted decodes just fine with the library:

http://zxing.org/w/decode?u=http%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FhCj3w.jpg

Something is wrong in your code, and it's impossible for anyone to say since there is no further detail. But this much should be OK.